# How to sort a table of elements based on a common label?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of elements with headers (time and length), and it can be seen in Fig 1 below (pls ignore the highlighted parts and treat them as "no fill" cells).
[image: Fig 1]

I want create a macro to concatenate all the "Time" columns together into a single column and arrange the values of "Length" based on it's corresponding Time values shown in Fig 1 above. To illustrate how it works, u can take a look at Fig 2 below to see the final arrangement of the table after the macro is ran to sort the table.

[image: Figure 2]

I have a slight idea on how to create the macro - Firstly, using the time column as key, I will attach ALL the length values corresponding to the key on (eg 3.29E-04 in column E attach to "Key" 0 in column D) and then concatenate the time values, and lastly, sorting the length values based on the keys that they were attached to to get the final table as shown in Fig 2. However, I do not know how to attach the length values to its corresponding key. Hence can someone teach me how to do it?

If not, is there any other methods to achieve the sorting of the table more efficiently? Pls advise me how to do it thank you.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?.. Hint - You can create 2D array of the range and then using loop can populate the data

Comment: In image 1, you can have up to how many pairs of time-length?

Comment: @TheGridLock .. Any number of pairs could be covered through range.currentrigion? It will be flexible.

Comment: one simple way I think you should use power query or BI to get all unique time then you can even combine it with vba, you just don't need sort, you just need lookup value corresponds to the time

Comment: How do i record a macro to sort the data? Or rather what steps should I do to create array and then use loop to populate the data? @NareshBhople

Comment: May I know what is BL? I need to sort these data in the manner above such that I can use that format of data to plot a graph so yeah.. @NareshBhople

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use VBA for this? This can easily be done with `VLokkUp` or `Index + Match`

Comment: Hi @Zac, I just need a way to automate these data and sort them to how it is in figure 2, so can u advise me on how to use vlookup to get the job done?

Comment: In column **O**, use this formula from **O3** to **O26**: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($N3,$D$3:$E$26,2,FALSE), 0)`. In column **P**, use this formula from **P3** to **P26**: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($N3,$F$3:$G$26,2,FALSE), 0)`. In column **Q**, use this formula from **Q3** to **Q26**: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($N3,$H$3:$I$26,2,FALSE), 0)`. In column **R**, use this formula from **R3** to **R26**: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($N3,$J$3:$K$26,2,FALSE), 0)`. You may have to play around with formatting (you may not) but that should get you the results you want

Comment: hi is this possible to turn into a vba code instead? sorry for the trouble and thanks so much for helping! @Zac

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use VBA for this then based on the assumption that your data is setup as you have in your query: add the below code to a module and run it

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetNewTable()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")       ' Change the sheet name
    Dim iLR As Long: iLR = oWS.Range("N" & oWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With oWS

        .Range("O3:O" & iLR).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP($N3,$D$3:$E$" & iLR & ",2,FALSE),0)"
        .Range("P3:P" & iLR).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP($N3,$F$3:$G$" & iLR & ",2,FALSE),0)"
        .Range("Q3:Q" & iLR).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP($N3,$H$3:$I$" & iLR & ",2,FALSE),0)"
        .Range("R3:R" & iLR).Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP($N3,$J$3:$K$" & iLR & ",2,FALSE),0)"

    End With

End Sub
```